# Can you change the desktop highlight colour in 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, customization

I know this question has been asked a couple of times, but none of the methods that I have seen work for 20.04

If there is a way to do it with the terminal, that would be good.

Answer (score 2):

The desktop highlight color is determined by the GTK theme you are using. Ubuntu comes with the Yaru theme that provides the orange accent color. No option is exposed to change that color in Ubuntu (Linux Mint, however, does that), so unless you know how to edit the code of the theme yourself, the only way is to change themes.

The theme can be changed using the Gmome Tweaks tool (not installed by default) or with a command, e.g. to change to the Adwaita theme with blue accent color:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme 'Adwaita'
```